# RXJS pipe filter inner(nested) property data

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to pipe and filter from an API response, but response format is as follows.

JSON:

> {
> activeAwards: [
> {
> name: 'x',
> status: 'valid'
> },
> {
> name: 'y',
> status: 'valid'
> },
> {
> name: 'z',
> status: 'invalid'
> }
> ]
> }

I have tried tap to get in 'activeAwards' and filter it.

Code:

```
  .pipe(
        tap(data => {
          data.activeAwards.filter(award => 
            award.status === 'valid';
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return error;
      });
```

But according to the code above I`m getting all 3 objects, which is all of them, it should be 2 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tap doesn't change streamed data and filter doesn't change the input array.
Instead use map and assign the filter result.

```
.pipe(
        map(data => {
          return {
            ...data, 
            activeAwards: data.activeAwards.filter(award => award.status === 'valid');
          };
        }),
      ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        return error;
      });
```

Comment: You can not create a new object, simply change the property activeAdwars:`.pipe(map(data => {data.activeAwards=data.activeAwards.filter(award => award.status === 'valid');return data}))`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to `map` to the filtered array since you're changing the data that needs to fall through to the subscribe:

```
.pipe(
  // catch the error before transforming the stream to prevent runtime errors
  catchError(() => {...})
  map((data) => {
    data.activeAwards = data.activeAwards.filter(...);
    return data;
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  //handle the data
});
```

`catchError` needs to return something in its callback. You can either return `EMPTY` (imported from `rxJs`) to cause the stream to never hit the subscribe block, or you can return `of(null)` and add handling in your subscribe for a null value.

```
.pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    return of(null)
    // or return EMPTY - the subscribe block will not run in this case.
  })
).subscribe(res => {
  if(res) {
    //handle the result
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestion, but when I add catchError to the top, I`m getting

'Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<CashBackList, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<CashBackList, CashBackList>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CashBackList'. '


How do we type error to the interface??

Comment: Ah, so you want to return something in the callback for catchError. I'll update the answer with some patterns I've used

Comment: return of(); <-- this worked return of(null) was still giving the same error

Comment: Oh, got your suggestion on top, this works too ->return EMPTY